# Animacion con Jquery, un fadeIn, un animate con desplazamiento a la derecha y demas

Tags: jquery, animación

Tengo que diseñar una animación con **jquery** con los elementos `fadeIn` Y `animate`. Muestro código para ser mas concreto.

Bueno, el asunto es este:

Debo de sobreponer o ocultar las 3 imágenes siguientes del **welcome** y alinearlas una tras otra con animación, se me ocurrió dos formas con un `animate` y que se mueva a la derecha por porcentaje o pixeles y la segunda es daándole un contenedor a donde desplazarse, pero este tipo de animación no lo encuentro en la web.

Adicional a eso, cómo se utiliza el `width` con corchetes.

Codigo de HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!--BOOTSTRAP CSS LIBRARY-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!--BOOTSTRAP CSS LIBRARY-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos.css">
    <title>Animacion de Entrada Grupo Empresarial SKY</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container-fluid fondo">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 tableroEncabezado">

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 tableroLogo">

        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 tableroFirma">

        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 tableroEscuela">

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--IMAGENES
    <img src="img/1.jpg" alt="imagen-bienvenido" id="bienvenido" class="bienvenido-css">
    <img src="img/2.png" alt="imagen-logo" id="logo" class="logo-css">
    <img src="img/3.jpg" alt="imagen-firma" id="firma" class="firma-css">
    <img src="img/4.png" alt="imagen-academia" id="escuela" class="escuela-css">
    -->
    <!--IMAGENES-->
    <!--BOOTSTRAP JS LIBRARY-->
    <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-wS9gmOZBqsqWxgIVgA8Y9WcQOa7PgSIX+rPA0VL2rbQ="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!--BOOTSTRAP JS LIBRARY-->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="js/app2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!--<script src="js/app.js"></script>-->
  </body>
</html>
```

Codigo de CSS:

```
.fondo{background-color: white;}
.logo-css{width: 260px;height: 260px; position: relative;}
.firma-css{position: relative;width: 260px;height: 260px;}
.escuela-css{position: relative;width: 260px;height: 260px;}
.bienvenido-css{position: relative;}
```

Codigo de JS:

```
$(function(){
  imagenAnimacion();
})

function imagenAnimacion(){
  var welcome= $("<img src='img/1.jpg' alt='imagen-bienvenido' id='bienvenido' class='bienvenido-css' style='display:none;'>");
  var logo= $("<img src='img/2.png' alt='imagen-logo' id='logo' class='logo-css' style='display:none;'>");
  var signal= $("<img src='img/3.jpg' alt='imagen-firma' id='firma' class='firma-css' style='display:none;'>");
  var school= $("<img src='img/4.png' alt='imagen-escuela' id='escuela' class='escuela-css' style='display:none;'>");
  $(".tableroEscuela").append(welcome);
  welcome.fadeIn(2000, function(){
    welcome.animate({
      "right":"+=150%"
      },"fast");
      $(".tableroEscuela").append(logo);
      logo.fadeIn(2000, function(){
        logo.animate({
          "right":"+=200%"
        },"fast");
      $(".tableroEscuela").append(signal);
      signal.fadeIn(2000, function(){
        logo.animate({
          "right":"+=150%"
          },"fast");
      $(".tableroEscuela").append(school);
      school.fadeIn(2000, function(){
        school.animate({
          "right":"+=100%"
        },"fast");
          });
        });
      });
    });
}
```